# Как превратить список списков пар слов в словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например

```
lst = [['pen','table'],['pen','apple'],['table','morning']]
```

Значить, что именно мне нужно сделать? А мне нужно, чтобы каждый элемент списка списков стал ключом к списку элементов с которыми он в паре.

```
lst = {'pen': ['table','apple'], 'table': ['pen','morning'], 'apple': ['pen'], 'morning': ['table']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = [['pen', 'table'], ['pen', 'apple'], ['table', 'morning']]

result = {}
for level1 in lst:
  for level2 in level1:
    elements = list(level1)
    elements.remove(level2)
    result[level2] = result.get(level2, []) + elements

print(result)

{'morning': ['table'], 'table': ['pen', 'morning'], 'pen': ['table', 'apple'], 'apple': ['pen']}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо .) Но если вам не трудно, не могли бы вы рассказать поподробние о последней строке .

Comment: @Bernard Последняя строка - это вывод результата :) А если Вы про result[level2] = result.get(level2, []) + elements, то в правой части ищется элемент в словаре или создается пустой список, если такого слова в ключах словаря еще нет. После этого к полученному списку (пустому или нет) добавляются элементы того же списка, но без самого слова. А после этого происходит присваивание словарю с тем же самым ключом.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо))

Answer (score 5):

В таких случаях [удобно `collections.defaultdict` использовать](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in lst:
    d[a].append(b)
    d[b].append(a)
```

`defaultdict` сам по себе как словарь работает, но если нужен точный тип, можно `dict(d)` вызвать.

#### Результат

```
{'apple': ['pen'],
 'morning': ['table'],
 'pen': ['table', 'apple'],
 'table': ['pen', 'morning']}
```

Comment: элегантное решение...

Answer (score 1):

Как дополнительный вариант без использования `defaultdict`, можно использовать метод [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) с похожим эффектом:

```
d = {}
for a, b in lst:
    d.setdefault(a, []).append(b)
    d.setdefault(b, []).append(a)
```

Метод `setdefault(key, default)` принимает ключ `key`, значение по умолчанию `default` и возвращает значение по ключу `key`. В случае, если такого ключа не было, он дополнительно добавляет ключ `key` с переданным значением `default`. Примерный его код следующий:

```
class dict:
    def setdefault(self, key, default):
        if key not in self:
            self[key] = default
        return self[key]
```

Недостатки этого решения следующие:

- Пустые списки создаются каждый раз, когда ключ в словаре уже есть.
- Метод `setdefault` имеет не очень понятное название.

Тем не менее, здесь мы обходимся стандартной функциональностью словаря.

---

Дополнительно, если требуется поддержать уникальность элементов по ключу (например, в случае, если пары могут повторяться с таким же или обратным порядком), стоит использовать `set`:

```
lst = [['pen', 'table'], ['pen', 'apple'], ['apple', 'pen'], ['table', 'morning']]    

d = {}
for a, b in lst:
    d.setdefault(a, set()).add(b)
    d.setdefault(b, set()).add(a)
```

Или, для решения с `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
for a, b in lst:
    d[a].add(b)
    d[b].add(a)
```

В этих случаях словарь `d` будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
{'apple': {'pen'},
 'morning': {'table'},
 'pen': {'apple', 'table'},
 'table': {'morning', 'pen'}}
```

вместо

```
{'apple': ['pen', 'pen'],
 'morning': ['table'],
 'pen': ['table', 'apple', 'apple'],
 'table': ['pen', 'morning']}
```